React Native with Expo app build give "No such module 'ExpoModulesCore'" error
I'm trying to build my React Native with Expo app on XCode. Everything seems to work with Pods but I'v got this error:

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve it?
expo version : 51.0.13
expo-modules-core version : 1.12.25
Xcode version : 16.0

I added use_expo_modules! in Podfile but no success :(

I have this problem too and use this and it working for me, you can try it :
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/18150


Change into the project directory by running: cd your/project/path

Run: npm install expo-modules-core

Run npx expo prebuild --clean

Run: cd ios

Run pod deintegrate

Run pod cache clean --all

Run: rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

Run pod install

Open the Xcode project workspace (.xcworkspace file)from within ios folder.

Select Any iOS Device (arm64).

Try to build or archive via Product menu.


